# Xdocument amend all attributes that match

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

This is driving me mad, I've been trying this for 2 days now.

I basically want to substitute values based on name.

I have xml as follows:

```
    <session>   
      <immediate>   
        <diff name="TEST_DIFF">
          <pivot name="(Original)">
            <grid-processor name="mdStoredShape"/>
            <axes>
              <axis position="SLICERS">
                <attribute name="Result Namespace" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection value="$NAMESPACE$"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Date" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection value="$DATEFROM$"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Book" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection value="$BOOK_NAME$" type="Book Hierarchy"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Measure" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <exclude value="PV"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Risk Source System" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection value="gdsldn"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Is Error">
                  <selection value="false"/>
                </attribute>
              </axis>
              <axis position="DISCRIMINATOR">
                <attribute name="Book" mode="ALL"/>
                <attribute name="Book" mode="ALL"/>
                <attribute name="Measure" mode="ALL"/>
              </axis>
              <axis position="RESULT">
                <attribute name="SUM(Money Value In(GBP))"/>
                <attribute name="COUNT_DISTINCT(Book)"/>
              </axis>
            </axes>
          </pivot>
          <pivot name="(New)">
            <grid-processor name="mdStoredShape"/>
            <axes>
              <axis position="SLICERS">
                <attribute name="Result Namespace" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection ref="$NAMESPACE$"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Date" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection ref="$DATETO$"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Book" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection value="$BOOK_NAME$" type="Book Hierarchy"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Measure" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <exclude ref="PV"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Risk Source System" mode="INCLUSIVE">
                  <selection value="gdsldn"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Is Error">
                  <selection value="false"/>
                </attribute>
              </axis>
              <axis position="DISCRIMINATOR">
                <attribute name="Book" mode="ALL"/>
                <attribute name="Book" mode="ALL"/>
                <attribute name="Measure" mode="ALL"/>
              </axis>
              <axis position="RESULT">
                <attribute name="SUM(Money Value In(GBP))"/>
                <attribute name="COUNT_DISTINCT(Book)"/>
              </axis>
            </axes>
            <source name="risk"/>
          </pivot>
        </diff>   
    </immediate> 
</session>
```

and I want to replace all $NAMESPACE$ values with an actual value.

Can someone help?

for additional info I was using

```
XElement xeNS = Xdoc.Descendants("selection").First(el => (String)el.Attribute("value").Value == "$NAMESPACE$");
            xeNS.SetAttributeValue("value", ns);
```

but this only replaces the first instance. I was hoping for a linq query then loop and apply the change?

Answer (score 1):

If thats all, why don't you use "xml".replace("oldavalue", "newvalue")?

Comment: I dont have that method in Xdocument?

Comment: I meant to work with xml as a string and to use string.Replace. Anyway your mistake is in first. Change First to Where

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out in the end - selecting the correct attribute then looping over the elements..

> var query = from x in Xdoc.Descendants("selection")
>                            where x.Attribute("value").Value == "$BOOK_NAME$"
>                            select x;
>
> ```
>         foreach (XElement xe in query)
>         {
>             xe.Attribute("value").Value = book;                
>         }
> ```